# match multi-line string

Tags: regex, powershell

I am using a PowerShell command to find all *.vue files (it's a simple text format) in a directory, where I need to match this:

```
7,Id
6,Default
```

So, these are 2 consecutive lines. With Notepad++ I see CRLF at the end of the line. Following Google searches, this must be close:

```
Get-ChildItem "D:\Wim\TM1\TI processes" -Filter *.vue -Recurse |
  Select-String -Pattern "7,Id\r\n6,Default" -CaseSensitive |
  Out-File C:\test.txt
```

But it does not find the files. I checked that I can find the first part (`7,Id`) correctly, and also the second part (`6,Default`), but the combination with the newline is not working.

Any ideas please? Maybe an alternative?

I can have a workaround but it's inefficient and a lot of coding. For example, I could use PowerShell to provide a list of only the first sentence, then process these files to see if it matches the second sentence as well. I want to avoid that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the content of the file as a single string, otherwise `Select-String` will apply the pattern to each line separately.

```
Get-ChildItem "D:\Wim\TM1\TI processes" -Filter *.vue -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
  Get-Content $_.FullName | Out-String |
    Select-String -Pattern "7,Id\r\n6,Default" -CaseSensitive |
    Select-Object -Expand Matches |
    Select-Object -Expand Groups |
    Select-Object -Expand Value
} | Out-File C:\test.txt
```

On PowerShell v3 and newer you can use `Get-Content -Raw` instead of `Get-Content | Out-String`.

As an alternative to `Select-String` you could use the `-cmatch` operator in a `Where-Object` filter:

```
Get-ChildItem "D:\Wim\TM1\TI processes" -Filter *.vue -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
  Get-Content $_.FullName | Out-String | Where-Object {
    $_ -cmatch "7,Id\r\n6,Default"
  } | ForEach-Object {
    $matches[0]
  }
} | Out-File C:\test.txt
```

Comment: Hello,

Weird !

I was going to post that the second suggestion of Ansgar Wiechers works, but only once ! Not sure I understand what is going on, but I got the result of the 2 lines in my file C:\test.txt, and since then I cannot reproduce the success anymore. No C:\test.txt is created.

The first suggestion of Ansgar Wiechers and the suggestion by jj27, did not return the file "C:\test.txt" from the beginning.

Thank you for your feedback already !

Comment: Check the pipeline step by step. Does `Get-ChildItem` list the relevant files? Do they actually contain the lines in question? Does the `Where-Object` actually match something? Does the `ForEach-Object` output the relevant lines? If the input hasn't changed there's no reason why the above statements should work only once.

Comment: Apologies, it was the way of copy/pasting by myself. As I copied your solutions from SO, I pasted and >> appeared in front of the lines. I entered and nothing happened. Then I understood to create 1 long sentence and press Enter. Bingo ! Both solutions work, thank you very much ! Just 1 follow-up question: can we also have the fullname (path and filename) in the output text file rather than the 2 matching lines ? Then it's perfect.

Comment: Sure. Put the path in a variable and echo that variable before echoing `$matches[0]`.

Comment: Thanks, but I am still new to PowerShell scripting. This code works perfectly: Get-ChildItem "D:\Wim\TM1\TI processes" -Filter *.vue -Recurse | ForEach-Object { Get-Content $_.FullName | Out-String | Where-Object { $_ -cmatch "7,Id\r\n6,Par défaut" } | ForEach-Object { $matches[0] } } | Out-File C:\test.txt   Instead of 7,Id and 6,Par défaut I would like to return the fullname of the file. Can you help me a last time ? Thanks !

Comment: If you want just the filename in the output file you can simply do this: `Get-ChildItem ... | Where-Object {Get-Content $_.FullName | Out-File) -cmatch "..."} | Select-Object -Expand FullName | Out-File ...`

Comment: Thank you but it throws a syntax error, I have filled in the ellipsis as follows: Get-ChildItem "D:\Wim\TM1\TI processes" | Where-Object {Get-Content $_.FullName | Out-File) -cmatch "7,Id\r\n6,Par défaut"} | Select-Object -Expand FullName | Out-File C:\test.txt

Comment: Missing closing '}' in statement block.
At line:1 char:91

Comment: It's actually a missing opening parenthesis before `Get-Content`.

Comment: Thanks. Now no syntax error anymore but I am asked to enter the FilePath: cmdlet Out-File at command pipeline position 2
Supply values for the following parameters:
FilePath:

Comment: The filter was supposed to be `Where-Object {(Get-Content $_.FullName | Out-String) -cmatch "..."}`. Sorry, it was late yesterday.

Comment: This is great, thank you very much. If you would ever need help with Excel / VBA, just let me know. I have been Excel MVP for 4 years. Enjoy your weekend.

Answer (score 0):

With `Select-String`, the `-Pattern` parameter is regex capable, so try this:

```
Get-ChildItem "D:\Wim\TM1\TI processes" -Filter *.vue -Recurse |
  Select-String -Pattern "7,Id|6,Default" -CaseSensitive |
  Out-File C:\test.txt
```

The vertical pipe bar (`|`) acts as an alternative separator, or in otherwords, an "or" operator. With the pattern it will match either.

Comment: Using an alternation would produce false positives, e.g. when the strings appear in the wrong order, or one of them is missing altogether.

Comment: Indeed, I need to match these lines litterally, no other lines can be in between and also the correct order must be applied.